# Query using email address to get user ID as key to query a second table

Tags: mysql

The User table has UserEmail and UserID

The Purchases table uses UserID as the key.

Currently I am manually doing a UserEmail search on the User table to find out User IDs then manually searching the Purchases table to export records. I would really love help with a query (which I'll use with Phpmyadmin) so I can do 1 query on the Purchases table using UserEmail to get results.

I hope this makes sense and I thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM User, Purchases 
WHERE User.UserID = Purchases.UserID 
AND User.UserEmail = 'user@email.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

The is called a 'join':

```
select* from user join purchases using (userid) where useremail = ?
```

Comment: I've discovered this query exports all Purchases records. Is there a line I can add that will limit the export to Purchases for this UserID? Thanks all.